# Modx Ditto display count

Tags: content-management-system, modx, ditto

Can i use a variable inside Ditto placeholder? 
For example

```
[!Ditto? &tpl=`TPL-jc` &display=$myVar]
```

instead of

```
[!Ditto? &tpl=`TPL-jc` &display=`10`]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another Element inside a Ditto placeholder, e.g.

```
[!Ditto? &tpl=`TPL-jc` &display=`[+myVar+]`]
```

(that's myVar as a placeholder)

```
[!Ditto? &tpl=`TPL-jc` &display=`[myVar]`]
```

(that's myVar as a Snippet that outputs the value you want)

```
[!Ditto? &tpl=`TPL-jc` &display=`[*myVar*]`]
```

(that's myVar as a Template Variable)